Android target 14 - Starting FGS with type location
I'm using foreground service type as location to fetch location through the service. it will fetch every 2 mins interval. service get start and stopped, after 2 mins again it will get start and stopped and it continues both in background and foreground.
So now, in here I have given all the permission before start,
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

So now app in background and gps location turned off, I got the crash in next foreground service location update start.
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to create service com.lystloc.utils.services.tracking.LocationUpdateService: java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type location callerApp=ProcessRecord{c137f46 23529:com.lystloc/u0a332} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION] any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION] and the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission

Thanks in advance

Apparently, you are in violation of one of the rules cited in the Unable to create service error line. My guess is that comes from the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission. I do not know how you intend for "after 2 mins again it will get start and stopped and it continues both in background and foreground" to work on modern versions of Android, where that sort of behavior is blocked. Your [mcve] does not show how you are doing that, and my guess is that is where your problem lies.

by the alarm manager I have rescheduled for every 5 mins,
Location enabled = Can start the service in the foreground
Location enabled = Can start the service in the background
Location disabled = Can start the service in the foreground
Location disabled = Crash when attempting to start the service in the background

You cannot start foreground services from the background on modern versions of Android, except in very limited circumstances. Last I checked, AlarmManager is not one of those circumstances.

Can you suggest any solution on this?

Keep the foreground service running, at least as long as the device manufacturer lets you.

Yellow, I came across this error too, and I tried to compile my experience in this answer. Feel free to take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78998745/12810465
